# Solve for "n" in an annuity due with a balloon value

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am attempting to determine for formula for "n" in an annuity due (aka annuity in advance) where there is a balloon value involved. I have been unable to determine the formula myself.

Here are the formulas for n as an Ordinary Annuity, Advance Annuity, and n as an Ordinary Annuity with a balloon value. FV represents the balloon value.

- PV = Present Value
- PMT = Payment
- i = interest rate
- n = number of periods
- ln = natural log
- FV = Future Value (aka balloon payment)

Here are the formulas that I have so far:

$n$ (arrears):
$$ n = \frac{\ln \left[ \left( 1-\frac{\text{PV}(i)}{\text{PMT}}\right)^{-1}\right]}{\ln (1+i)} $$

$n$ (arrears w/ balloon):
$$ n = \frac{ \ln \left[ \frac{\text{PMT}-\text{FV}(i)}{\text{PMT}-\text{PV}(i)} \right]}{\ln (1+i)}$$

$n$ (advance):

$$ n = \frac{ \ln \left[ \left(1+i\left(1-\frac{\text{PV}}{\text{PMT}}\right)\right)^{-1}\right]}{\ln (1+i)} + 1 $$

(original link: http://danieljlong.com/tvm/n.png)

As a potential starting point, here is the formula for the balloon value (in advance):

$FV$ (advance as balloon):

$$ FV =  PV(1 + i)^n -\left[\text{(1 + i)} \times \text{PMT}\left[\frac{(1 + i)^n - 1}{i}\right]\right] $$

As another potential starting point, here is the formula for PMT (advance) w/ a balloon:

$PMT$ (advance w/balloon):

$$ PMT = \left(PV - \frac{FV}{(1 + i)^n} \right) \times \frac{i}{1 - (1 + i)^{-n}} \times 
\frac{1}{(1 + i)} $$